# How to calculate an rf amplifier stage

Tags: amplifier, rf, radio, ham-radio

I changed the LC tank of the circuit below for operation in the 2m ham radio band (144-146MHz, I'm a licenced Class A Ham). Now I'd like to add an amplifier stage to increase the output by about 30dB.
I think a good candidate for this would be a BFR 93A transistor. So of course I have to remove the low pass filter (L2, L3, C12). But from there I struggle to calculate the base current for the BFR 93A and so on. The output after C5 is at about -4.5 to -7.5dBm. Besides the 7V supply there's also 12VDC available for the collector of the BFR 93A.

Can someone help me?
[image]

Could this be an approach for an amplifying stage? I would connect C1 instead of C5 of the existing circuit and go from there. I could live with an output of around 20dBm.

[image]

Comment: The clever money would be on using a simulator to develop the circuit above.

Comment: @Laurin Please write a specific question.

Comment: Putting two and two together: you're asking for a modest fraction of a watt (23-26dBm), from a tiny SOT-23 transistor -- that might be *just* possible, but you should probably consider using something bigger here. Whether filtering or matching is required between stages, depends.

Comment: "I changed the LC tank of the circuit below" -- what circuit below?

Comment: Sorry Tim, I accidently deleted the link for the first picture